# ImageView Rotation behaves weird after Zooming

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I have a `UISlider` for zooming the `imageView`(instead of `UIPinchGesture`) and i'm using `UIRotationGesture`,both of them works fine independently.Zooming without doing rotation gesture works fine! but Once i perform a rotation and them zoom in or out the `imageview` it behaves weird as it looses the rotation scale.(that's what i guess!)
How do i fix this?

Well im not good with this maths stuff struggling with this since few days and i have searched through the forums couldn't find the solution. Kindly help me:)

**For Zooming**:(here i'm not handling transform as im unsure of)

```
-(void)scale:(UISlider *)sender
{
      float sliderValue = [sender value];
    CGRect newFrame = placeRing.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(sliderValue, sliderValue);
    placeRing.frame = newFrame;
}
```

**For rotation**:

```
- (void)twoFingersRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    isRotated = TRUE;
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
         rotation= recognizer.rotation;
    rotatedTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate([placeRing transform], [recognizer rotation]);
        placeRing.transform = rotatedTransform;
       [recognizer setRotation:0];
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation applies transform which invalidates the frame property you are using to resize the view. Use bounds and center properties to zoom.

See the warning box in: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

```
-(void)scale:(UISlider *)sender
{
    float sliderValue = [sender value];
    placeRing.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, sliderValue, sliderValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,Well the problem is i can't specify the bounds here because the x and y keeps on changing so i can't set it that was the reason i had to use the frame:(

Comment: I'm sorry Dalee, but I don't understand why you can't use bounds and center to do whatever you are trying to do with frame? Could you try to explain this to me please?

Comment: Ok my x and y Coordinates keeps changing so while zooming in and out i dont want to modify x and y coordinates i just need to modify the width and height thats the reason im using frame instead of bounds because in bounds i will have to specify the x and y cordinates along with width and height.

Comment: Ok, you should not worry about the 0,0 in bounds. :) The bounds really just set the size, the x and y of the rect are ignored and to my knowledge are required to be 0,0 when setting the bounds. If you are changing the position of the view somewhere in your code, and you have transform property set to anything other than 0, you must use the center property instead of the frame's x and y fields. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow!! superb that works and thanks for the explanation i will accept your answer !! but now got a different problem:)

Comment: Now the problem is i have a set of images from wich i can select and the selected images are added to that imageView..now while i have rotated the image view if i select a different image the image disorts  .so is there a way to add the image as per the old imageview's rotation angle?

Comment: Ok sorted again your theory worked!! I had to set the bounds again while changing the images based on the boolean...:) Thanks man!
superb:)